# How to save Darktable edits as a file?

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, file-management, darktable, file-format

Darktable is a non-destructive photo editor that exports to jpeg, png and .xcf (whatever that is, but seems to be the Gimp file format), but doesn't save a workfile containing all the individual preset edits? Why not, how to save those settings for back-up and future reference?

Comment: It save them in special database file. And also in XMP file (which are one per image)

Comment: what's the database file. and what is xmp format

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform

Comment: The database file is .xmp?

Comment: no, this is additional file. Darktable store these settings in specific database (search for library): https://docs.darktable.org/usermanual/3.8/en/special-topics/program-invocation/darktable/  XMP is so named side file which in pair with RAW file can be used to reproduce the image and settings

Comment: what is the file format extension of Darktable's database file? That link is complicated

Comment: @RomeoNinov sidecar files work with jpg and other formats not only RAW

Comment: @user610620 Darktable uses SQLite for its database.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens, it depends. In Lightroom XMP info is incorporated in JPG, DNG, so LR do not create XMP file for these formats

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens The Darktable SQLite database has no file extension? Also what is the database's filename and its relative directory (location)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov That's Lightroom, not Darktable. In my opinion, it's a stupid decision since it is not rigorously non-destructive (idempotent). YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Darktable saves edits in sidecar files. Sidecar files have the file extension `.xmp` and are a list of instructions to reproduce the history of edits.

Because the edits are stored as instructions in the sidecar file, no changes need to be made to the original image whether it is RAW, JPG, TIF, DNG, or something else. That's why Darktable is considered non-destructive (another term for "non-destructive editing" is non-linear editing).

Darktable stores *meta-data* about the source and the edits in its databases. The databases are managed using SQLite3. On Ubuntu, they are located in `~/.config/darktable`. The file `library.db` contains metadata about pictures and their edits. There is also `data.db` containing data for styles and module presets. Both can be explored (and modified) using standard SQLite tools.

Unlike RawTherappee where sidecar files are more or less human readable, Darktable's sidecar files are rather cryptic. They are however, in plain text and can be manipulated using your favorite text tools. It is also possible to create new sidecar files by copying and editing an existing file...this is what the "duplicate" action does within Darktable...it just creates a new sidecar file.

Comment: Don't have Ubuntu, is it possible to locate the database on Windows 10?

Comment: @user610620 Of course it is possible but I don’t have Darktable on Windows. However it sounds like you do. Have you looked using the file explorer?

Comment: Not sure whhere to look

Comment: I just discovered recently that in addition darktable also write the instructions to the metadata of _exported_ images by default, so you can restore them from the exported jpg, in case you lost the raw's sidecar and database.  However, this also means that when you share the exported file, you also share your edits, which may not always be desired.

Comment: And another comment: While I think it is enabled by default, writing of xmp sidecar files can be disabled in the settings (in which case the edits are only saved in the database).  So in case you don't get sidecar files, check the settings.

Comment: is there an option when saving a jpeg to tell Darktable not to save those edit instructions inside the jpeg? and how does one view/open those edit instructions from the jpeg in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @user610620 It is a bit hidden: Click on the presets-button of the export module, it has an option "preferences..." at the bottom.  There you can disable the "develop history" checkbox.  I have to admit, I don't know how you can view/load the instructions.  I assumed you just need to import the jpg in darktable but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows `data.db` and `library.db` are in the `darktable` folder under your `Local` %APPDATA% folder:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\darktable

C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\darktable>dir *.db
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is E093-B4E9

 Directory of C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\darktable

2022-07-11  09:00           688,128 data.db
2022-07-10  18:35         2,752,512 library.db
```